# Google Calendar API - How do I create a QUICK ADD event using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm just learning Google's Calendar API and can't figure out how to create a Quick Add Event using javascript. Is this possible? Are there any examples or documentation?

Here's what's not working - Rather than creating an event tomorrow at 10am called "Coffee", the following code creates an event set for whatever time I posted it, and puts "Coffee tomorrow 10am" in the description field.

```
function createEvent() {

    var calendarService = new google.gdata.calendar.CalendarService('GoogleInc-jsguide-1.0');

    var feedUri = 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/my-calendar-url/private/full';

    var entry = new google.gdata.calendar.CalendarEventEntry();

    entry.setContent(new google.gdata.atom.Text.create("Coffee tomorrow 10am"));

    entry.setQuickAdd(true);

    var callback = function (result) {
        $('#panel').html('event created!');
    }

    var handleError = function (error) {
        $('#panel').html(error);
    }

    calendarService.insertEntry(feedUri, entry, callback, handleError, google.gdata.calendar.CalendarEventEntry);

}
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I doing right?

Thanks!

-alex-

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add an event date the minimum data needed I guess is "What" and "When"

i.e

```
// Create a When object that will be attached to the event
var when = new google.gdata.When();

// Set the start and end time of the When object
var startTime = google.gdata.DateTime.fromIso8601("2008-02-10T09:00:00.000-08:00");
var endTime = google.gdata.DateTime.fromIso8601("2008-02-10T10:00:00.000-08:00");
when.setStartTime(startTime);
when.setEndTime(endTime);

// Add the When object to the event
entry.addTime(when);
```

So if you change your code above to

```
function createEvent() {

var calendarService = new google.gdata.calendar.CalendarService('GoogleInc-jsguide-1.0');

var feedUri = 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/my-calendar-url/private/full';

var entry = new google.gdata.calendar.CalendarEventEntry();

entry.setTitle(new google.gdata.atom.Text.create("Coffee tomorrow 10am"));

var when = new google.gdata.When();
var startTime = google.gdata.DateTime.fromIso8601("2008-02-10T09:00:00.000-08:00");
var endTime = google.gdata.DateTime.fromIso8601("2008-02-10T10:00:00.000-08:00");
when.setStartTime(startTime);
when.setEndTime(endTime);
entry.addTime(when);

var callback = function (result) {
        $('#panel').html('event created!');
}

var handleError = function (error) {
        $('#panel').html(error);
}

calendarService.insertEntry(feedUri, entry, callback, handleError, google.gdata.calendar.CalendarEventEntry);

}
```

That should work, take note I changed the `setContent` to `setTitle`

**------------------------ EDIT -----------------------------**

The answer above is for adding events normally, initially did not get the question.  But for addning quick events it should be

```
function createEvent() {

    var calendarService = new google.gdata.calendar.CalendarService('GoogleInc-jsguide-1.0');

    var feedUri = 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/my-calendar-url/private/full';

    var entry = new google.gdata.calendar.CalendarEventEntry();

    entry.setContent(new google.gdata.atom.Text.create("Coffee June 25 10am-10:30am"));

    entry.setQuickAdd(true);

    var callback = function (result) {
        $('#panel').html('event created!');
    }

    var handleError = function (error) {
        $('#panel').html(error);
    }

    calendarService.insertEntry(feedUri, entry, callback, handleError, google.gdata.calendar.CalendarEventEntry);

}
```

take note of the setContent it should be clear what dates you want to quick add the event to

Comment: Hey Raymund, thanks for the answer. Isn't the point of a Quick Add, that I don't need to specify a separate what/when? That it interprets it from the string?

Comment: Again, thank you. But your code addresses creating an event, but I'm looking to create a "QuickAdd" event. Any ideas?

Comment: I also remember I had an issue with the .Net API before, so I changed the http to https, let me know if this resolves the issue so I can update the answer

Comment: I'm not receiving an error, I'm just getting a different result than I was expecting. I want to create an event with title/time in one string (Quick Add). But what my above code does is create an event at the time of creation with my string as description, rather than extrapolating the title/time from the string.

Comment: can you change the text instead to "Coffee June 25 10am-10:30am".  I tried it in my instance it works.  It looks like "tommorow" cannot be deciphered